# Show data in view blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have query :

```
$data = DB::select('SELECT YEAR(start_date) AS Year, 
      count(activity) AS qty,managing FROM data_xxx GROUP 
       BY(start_date),managing');
```

and called it in "result" view :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Statistik Realisasi Kerjasama</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>

    <th>Name</th>
    <th>2019</th>
    <th>2020</th>
    <th>2021</th>
</tr>
<tr>
@foreach($data as $jj)

    <td>{{$jj->managing}}</td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2019 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2020 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2021 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
@endforeach
</tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer clearfix">
              <ul class="pagination pagination-sm no-margin pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
```

result :

[image]

how to echo it in blade so it become like this :

[image]

> "2019,2020,2021" data from YEAR(start_date) AS Year
>
> "data1 and data2" from managing
>
> "1" from  count(activity) AS qty

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this:

```
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>2019</th>
    <th>2020</th>
    <th>2021</th>
</tr>
<tr>
@foreach($data as $jj)

    <td>{{$jj->managing}}</td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2019 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2020 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2021 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
@endforeach
</tr>
```

with this:

```
<tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>2019</th>
    <th>2020</th>
    <th>2021</th>
</tr>
@foreach($data as $key => $jj)
<tr>
    <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
    <td>{{$jj->managing}}</td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2019 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2020 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
    <td>{{$jj->year == 2021 ? $jj->qty : ''}} </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Please paste your whole blade view in your question

Comment: i have paste whole blade view

Comment: it works...thank you!!
but if I want to retrieve data for <th> 2019 </ th> from YEAR (start_date) AS Year. what should i change?

Comment: It's already there. If $jj->year is 2019 then it will show the qty and if not then it will show nothing

Comment: yes..i mean what should i change, so, I don't need to enter the year manually on <th> 2019 </ th> section

Comment: That is hard... maybe you can make a foreach loop for the  <th> and echo the year